# dynamic linking for a kernel module

Tags: linux-device-driver

That is, can a driver try to import a symbol for another driver, and if the symbol doesn’t exist can the driver continue to load without resolving the import? And even if possible is it even allowed for an upstream driver ? i.e a driver already out there in the lnux kernel?

Comment: *"if the symbol doesn’t exist can the driver continue to load"* - You should assume the driver module will not be loaded.  The unresolved symbol, when accessed, would cause a kernel panic.  The kernel is simply not going to allow an action that can obviously cause a panic.

Answer (score 4):

symbols exported by EXPORT_SYMBOL or EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(if the importing module does have GPL-compatible license) in any kernel modules can be used by other modules.

> if the symbol doesn’t exist can the driver continue to load without resolving the import?

I am not sure about it. But you can verify if a symbol is exported from the output of `cat /proc/kallsyms`. exported symbols will have two entries. One with symbol name and another with _*ksymtab* prefixed.

For example, for printk.

ffffffff814fd1e2 T printk
ffffffff81812550 r __ksymtab_printk

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I meant can the driver pro grammatically  look for a symbol ( if it is exported or not) and depending on that continue to load ?